# Push view controller from modal into navigation controller used by parent of the modal using Storyboard segues

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

First of all, I did look around and found some similar questions, but none of the answers to those showed if it is possible to do using Storyboard segues and how.

I am using Storyboard segues and the design I have in mind is the following:

[Navigation Controller] - nested -> [Controller 1] - present modally over context -> [Controller 2] - pushed -> [Controller 3]

I set up the above design and it works just fine visually, and I can move back and forth between all three controllers, but I expected `Controller 3` to be nested in `Navigation Controller`, as it was pushed from `Controller 2`, which in turn was presented modally from `Controller 1` which was nested in `Navigation Controller`.

I assumed that pushing `Controller 3` from `Controller 2` was actually pushing it to the existing `Navigation Controller`, as parent of the modal was nested in there...

Oh, and my original problem was the following: I was trying to use `UIViewController#isMovingFromParent` from `Controller 3` when unwinding back to `Controller 2` and it always returned false.

Answer (score 1):

Aha, it seems that using `UIViewController#isBeingDismissed` provides the desired effect. I knew that it worked from the modally presented controller, but it seems it also works for pushed controllers, that is if they were pushed from the modally presented view controllers.

I still have so much to learn.